# How to submit an "unicode float" to App Engine's NDB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

Currently I'm building a very basic "electronic wallet/purse" database/app. What I do is (via a form) capture 3 main things:

- Name
- Email
- First Purchase

And populate another relevant data automatically...

**model.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Purse(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  token = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  password = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
  qr_img = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
  balance = ndb.FloatProperty(indexed=False)
  first_purchase = ndb.FloatProperty(indexed=False)
  activation_date = ndb.DateProperty(indexed=False)
  status = ndb.BooleanProperty(indexed=False)
```

For example, from the **first_purchase** parameter I populate the **balance** parameter every time a new purse gets created (by giving it 10% of the first_purchase value via a **percentage** method); Here you have the basics of my implementation:

**new.html (view):**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>E-wallet OptiVisión</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/overrides.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f5f5f5; background-image: none; color: #777777;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="formfill" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
    <img id="optiletras" src="../img/optivision-logo-transparent.png" alt="">
      <h1 class="formtext" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Nuevo Monedero</h1>
      <form method="post" action="/purses/new">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control formboot" placeholder="Nombre"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control formboot" placeholder="E-mail"/><br/>
        <div class="input-group formboot">
          <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
          <input type="number" name="first_purchase" class="form-control" placeholder="Primera Compra (Monto en M.N.)" step="0.01">
          <div class="input-group-addon">MXN</div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"/>
        <br />
        <br />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.py (NEW method):**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class New(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('new.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

    def post(self):
        self.purse = Purse(name = self.request.get('name'),
                               email = self.request.get('email'),
                               token = tokengen(),
                               password = passgen(),
                               qr_img = qrgen(),
                               first_purchase = self.request.get('first_purchase'),
                               balance = percentage(10, self.request.get('first_purchase'))
                            )
        self.purse.put()
        delivery()
        self.redirect('/purses/index')
```

**extras.py (PERCENTAGE method):**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Calcular Porcentajes
def percentage(percent, whole):
  return (float(percent) * float(whole)) / 100.0
```

The problem I'm having right now is that, (when creating a new purse via the form), app engine throws the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/optivisionmx/controllers/purse.py", line 53, in post
    balance = percentage(10, self.request.get('first_purchase'))
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2872, in __init__
    self._set_attributes(kwds)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2918, in _set_attributes
    prop._set_value(self, value)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1108, in _set_value
    value = self._do_validate(value)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1055, in _do_validate
    value = self._call_shallow_validation(value)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1247, in _call_shallow_validation
    return call(value)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1294, in call
    newvalue = method(self, value)
  File "/home/invitado/GoogleAppEngine/GAE-PythonSDK/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1580, in _validate
    (value,))
**BadValueError: Expected float, got u'2999'**
```

I've tried everything that comes into my mind to solve it and app engine still doesn't save a new purse when it's created.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
balance = percentage(10, self.request.get('first_purchase'))
```

the `request.get` returns a string (Unicode, but, that's a detail).  I don't know what your `percentage` function does, but it seems to me that all you need is to turn either the argument, or `percentage`'s return value, or both, into `float`s:

```
balance = float(percentage(10, float(self.request.get('first_purchase'))))
```

One of the two calls to `float` is no doubt redundant, but, can't tell which one without seeing your code for `percentage`!-)

Comment: This is indeed accurate, I had to modify the percentage function in a similar way of what you did here (in my case not in the controller but in "extras.py"), to return a float for the balance parameter (not only I had to make both arguments floats but also the result itself);

However, the problem the server was whining about was the "first_purchase" parameter not being a float itself (for it's own field not the "balance" one)

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

**controller.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class New(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('new.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

    def post(self):
        self.purse = Purse(name = self.request.get('name'),
                               email = self.request.get('email'),
                               token = tokengen(),
                               password = passgen(),
                               qr_img = qrgen(),
                               first_purchase = float(self.request.get('first_purchase')),
                               balance = percentage(10, self.request.get('first_purchase'))
                            )
        self.purse.put()
        delivery()
        self.redirect('/purses/index')
```

**extras.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Calcular Porcentajes
def percentage(percent, whole):
  return float((float(percent) * float(whole)) / 100.0)
```

The issue the server was whining about was the **"first_purchase"** parameter wasn't being submitted as a float for it's own field, ended up fixing that and returning a float for **balance** beforehand too.